i want to set boolean while get notification on background in flutter in Android value saving successfully and for IOS it's not working

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  log("message $message");
  await GetStorage.init();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  LocalStorage.instance.setIsPromptAvailable(true);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  translations.loadTranslations();
  await GetStorage.init();
  Utils.initializeTimeZone();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  NotificationService.initialize();
  await NotificationService().listenNotification();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  Get.put(AuthController());
  runApp(const MyApp());
}


i want to set boolean value
LocalStorage.instance.setIsPromptAvailable(true);
while get notification on background.
